# jQuery toggle mouseover/enter & mouseout with a simple function

Tags: jquery, replace, toggle, mouseevent

I have html.

```
<p class="textlimity" title="heyheyhey"> asd</p>
```

now in js i would like to toggle the textlimity text() on mouseover and mouseout so i written.

```
var textlimity = "";
var texlimity_temp = "";


$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.textlimity').live('mouseenter',function(){
     textlimity = $(this).attr("title");
     textlimity_temp = $(this).html();

     $(this).html(textlimity);
    }).live('mouseout',function(){
         setTimeout(function(){console.log(textlimity_temp);$(this).html(textlimity_temp); },200);
    });

});
```

logic is simple:
on mouseover the .textlimity title="" val() replaces the .textlimity

.html() , and do the opposite on mouseout

I used .html() cause i could have both plain text or html code inside both title="" or

any suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is and adaptation of [@David's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620377/jquery-toggle-mouseover-enter-mouseout-with-a-simple-function/7620452#7620452) with all issues resolved..

```
$('.textlimity').live('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    clearTimeout( self.data('restore') );
    if (!self.data('saved')) {
        self.data('saved', self.html()); // store the original content
    }
    self.html(this.title); // set content from title
}).live('mouseout', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.data( 'restore', setTimeout(function() {
        self.html(self.data('saved')); // revert to the stored content
    }, 200) );
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dQTDZ/4/

Answer (score 1):

Looks a bit complicated. How about:

```
$('.textlimity').live('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).data( 'saved', $(this).html() ) // store the original content
           .html( this.title ); // set content from title
}).live('mouseout',function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
         $(this).html( $(this).data('saved') ); // revert to the stored content
     }, 200);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQTDZ/

Comment: yep it works good, the only thing i would like is some delay when restoring html or some fadeIn fadeOut effects cause as it is now it looks too fast :P

Comment: @David, you need to store a reference to the `this` because `setTimeout` is executed out of current context.. Also the current logic, if you move the mouse a bit fast on/off the element, it will store at the `saved` data the `title` (*if it has not yet been restored by the timeout*) and will effectively lose the original value forever..

Comment: yep it doesn't works with setTimeout i was trying too, but it replaces but not returns to original text/html :(

Comment: @ispuk the code for the timeout to work correctly can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dQTDZ/1/

Comment: yep but is not David's code this is your :P you shold post an answer :)

Comment: then please see my edit http://jsfiddle.net/dQTDZ/2/  first time it is ok second time i pass mouseover and out and nothing happening, i'm on FF6++

Comment: i founded that using <a> instead of <p> elements it works better, but i can't use <a> :)))